# How to check the uniqueness of a field

Tags: unique-field

I need to check persEmail field whether it is used by another person account or not . When i tried to make it unique by checking the checkbox inside the field , it throws error like "Error: Duplicate value(s) found when building unique index". i.e It is checking the duplicacy for the pre existing records also.

If i use soql , the timeout exception will occur since there will be so many records in my prod (say : 10 billion). So my question is , i need to check for the newly created account persEmail field whether it has been used previously or not.

How to resolve this ? Please provide me a solution guys !!!

Comment: what kind of SOQL do you use? I believe if you use correct SOQL query it would work, you don't have to query for 10 billion record, you need just to match the record with the name value in given field